# Initializing Class from constructor

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class BlobStorageHelper
    {
        private readonly StorageSharedKeyCredential _sharedKeyCredential;
        private readonly BlobClient _blobClient;
        
        public BlobStorageHelper(BlobClient blobClient)
        {
            _blobClient = blobClient;
            _sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountAccountName"),
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountKey"));
        }
    
        public async Task<string> GetFileAsync()
        {
            await using var stream = await _blobClient.OpenReadAsync();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
```

What would be the best pracitce to initialize the `_sharedKeyCredential`? Is it bad practice to initialize it like this? I am probably gonna make this class a Scoped so I can call it through DI.

Comment: it seems to me this is a personal preference question.

Comment: `What would be the best [practice] to [whatever]?` is one of the questions explicitly to [avoid asking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it [asks for the best practice to do something](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the comments that this is a personal preference question.  There is a sound way to design things.  There are many ways to pass in settings to a class.  Environment variables are one way.  App.Config, appsettings.json, or csdef files are other ways.  The strategy is that you do not want the class to be so rigidly dependent upon a single technique, namely environment variables, which makes your code fragile.

With that in mind, I think your constructors should be written to accept either an argument of `StorageSharedKeyCredential` and/or pass in 2 string arguments for the account name and key.

```
public static BlobStorageHelper (BlobClient blobClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential credential) 
{ ... }

public static BlobStorageHelper (BlobClient blobClient, string accountName, string accountKey) 
{ ... }
```

While environment variables are convenient, you do not want your class to be so fragile and rigid.  You can toss aside such rigidity, add flexibilty, and keep some of the convenience by have a static method read the enivironment variables and call the constructor:

```
public static BlobStorageHelper CreateFromEnvironment(BlobClient blobClient) 
=> new BlobStorageHelper(BlobClient blobClient, 
   Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountAccountName"),
   Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountKey"));
```

All of that said, you should add exception checks for null inputs.  And I find the named `BlobStorageHelper` to be too vague.